# incidence matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

It is known that the rank of the (unsigned) incidence matrix of a connected graph $G$ is $n-c_0$, where $n$ is the number of nodes and $c_0$ is either 1 (if the graph is bipartite) or 0 (otherwise). Accordingly, the nullity of the incidence matrix is $m-n+c_0$, where $m$ is the number of edges.

If $G$ is unicyclic and bipartite, then $m-n+c_0=1$ and hence the null space is spanned by vectors whose entries are $\pm 1$ only, whose pattern follows the bipartition of the graph. But what about more general graphs where $m-n+c_0>0$, and in particular of *non-bipartite* graphs with $m-n+c_0=1$? Is there a meaningful interpretation of the null space without passing to working on $\mathbb F_2$?